# Google Chrome version numbers

Tags: google-chrome

I was running the 3.x beta of Chrome.  Now that they've come out with a 3.x stable, I'm not sure if Chrome updated itself to use the stable.  I can't find version numbers anywhere.

Anybody know where to find out the version numbers for stable?  Otherwise, please just use this question as the "wiki" to keep track of the latest version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look in *About Google Chrome* under the spanner/wrench icon.  Mine says it's 3.0.195.21, and up to date.

Comment: The latest dev build is **4.0.206.1**.

Answer (score 2):

I updated google-chrome today to 3.0.195.21 and it shows it's up to date in Preferences/About Google Chrome.